# Rails Association and Foreign_Key Confusion, what should my foreign keys be?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

I can't seem to understand how this association should look and work. I know I have not been very rails like with the naming convention, but neither is the source DB where I get the data, I do not have the freedom to change the primary keys as they relate also to the real source database, which I use ETL to load into my rails database.

These are my models:

```
class Eclass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :elinks, :foreign_key => :concept_id
  has_many :eproperties, :through => :elinks
end

class Elink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eclass, :foreign_key => :concept_id
  belongs_to :eproperty, :foreign_key => :pconcept_id
end

class Eproperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :elinks, :foreign_key => :pconcept_id
  has_many :eclasses, :through => :elinks
end
```

And these are the MySQL table schemas:

```
mysql> DESC eclasses;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| class_id     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| concept_id   | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | 1       |                |
| concept_name | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| language_id  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESC elinks;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| schema_id   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| concept_id  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pconcept_id | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| data_type   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| language_id | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sequence    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> DESC eproperties;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| property_id   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pconcept_id   | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | 1       |                |
| property_name | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| language_id   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And here is the error I get back, looks like active record is executing a query with an empty column name:

```
irb(main):002:0> @eclass.eproperties
  ←[1m←[35mEproperty Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `eproperties`.* FROM `eproperties`
 INNER JOIN `elinks` ON `eproperties`.`` = `elinks`.`pconcept_id` WHERE `elinks`
.`eclass_id` IS NULL
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'elinks.eclass_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `epro
perties`.* FROM `eproperties` INNER JOIN `elinks` ON `eproperties`.`` = `elinks`.`pconcept_id` WHERE `elinks`.`eclass_id` IS NULL
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'elinks.eclass_id'
 in 'where clause': SELECT `eproperties`.* FROM `eproperties` INNER JOIN `elinks` ON `eproperties`.`` = `elinks`.`pconcept_id` WHERE `elinks`.`eclass_id` IS NULL
```

I would like to return The properties for a given class.

**UPDATE: I added the foreign key declarations per one answer. But still recieve a similar error. This is the new error.**

```
irb(main):001:0> @eclass = Eclass.first
  ←[1m←[36mEclass Load (140.6ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `eclasses`.* FROM `eclasses` LIMIT 1←[0m
=> #<Eclass id: 1, class_id: "0161-1#TM-005740#1", concept_id: "0161-1#01-004609#1", concept_name: "ACTUATOR ASSEMBLY,STEERING COLUMN", language_id:
 "0161-1#LG-000001#1", created_at: "2009-06-08 20:28:00", updated_at: "2009-02-03 08:14:00">
irb(main):002:0> @props = @eclass.eproperties
  ←[1m←[35mEproperty Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `eproperties`.* FROM `eproperties` INNER JOIN `elinks` ON `eproperties`.`` = `elinks`.`pconcept_id` WH
ERE `elinks`.`concept_id` IS NULL
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'eproperties.' in 'on clause': SELECT `eproperties`.* FROM `eproperties` INNER JOIN `elinks` ON `eproperties`.`` = `el
inks`.`pconcept_id` WHERE `elinks`.`concept_id` IS NULL
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'eproperties.' in 'on clause': SELECT `eproperties`.* FROM `eproperties` INNER JOIN `e
links` ON `eproperties`.`` = `elinks`.`pconcept_id` WHERE `elinks`.`concept_id` IS NULL
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:687:in `query'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:687:in `block in exec_qu
ery'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_r
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_r
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_r
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_r
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_r
ect_all'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_r

        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_r
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_r
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_r
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_r
et'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_r
        from c:in `load_target'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_r
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/comman
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/comman
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/comman
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Comment: I believe that you just need to specify the foreign key for the has_many associations just as you are for the belongs_to associations. In the error, it's expecting to join on elinks.eclass_id rather than elinks.concept_id. Also, so very sorry about the naming conventions that you're stuck with!

Comment: Indeed, the naming of my legacy databases are horrible, our legacy apps are ASP(the original), lots of vanilla HTMl and SQL. makes me cry at times.

Comment: Could you look at this again @Tom L , I added the foreign keys to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to set the correct primary keys for each table, so I think it would look something like this.

```
class Eclass < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :concept_id
  has_many :elinks, :foreign_key => :concept_id
  has_many :eproperties, :through => :elinks
end

class Elink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eclass, :foreign_key => :concept_id, :primary_key => :concept_id
  belongs_to :eproperty, :foreign_key => :pconcept_id, :primary_key => :pconcept_id
end

class Eproperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :pconcept_id
  has_many :elinks, :foreign_key => :pconcept_id
  has_many :eclasses, :through => :elinks
end
```

Comment: Does the actual mysql schema need to match these declarations?

Comment: No, it just lets rails know how it should join the tables.  No actual foreign keys need to exist in mysql for rails to setup the table relationship.  You might not need to specify primary_key in the Elink class since it declares them in the corresponding class, but I threw it in there in case it mattered.

Answer (score 0):

In the Elinks class I think you need to add the foreign key to the relationship:

```
has_many :elinks, :foreign_key => :concept_id
```

Comment: Do you mean the Eclass class?

Comment: Just noticed the ID columns are of type varchar. That is very bad and could be the cause of the issue, although in theory ActiveRecord shouldn't care and leave it to the database to generate the error. I would try out the SQL query manually as JOINing a varchar to ID really shouldn't work.

Comment: I'm not using any INT ID columns as primary or foreign keys, all my join keys are varchar.

Comment: That's not what your table descriptions say though, each table ID is an `int(11)`. ActiveRecord only joins foreign keys to primary keys AFAIK.